# Getting "Cannot find the type nvarchar(MAX)" when adding new CLR user defined function

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2012, clr, sql-types

I have created a new function in an assembly which has been successfully added as a CLR Assembly to my SQL server. Now I am trying to create a SQL user defined function to map to the new method in that assembly. I have other methods in the assembly which have been mapped successfully.

Here is my function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FromCamelCase](@value [nvarchar(MAX)])
RETURNS [nvarchar(MAX)] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [Tools_CLR].[UserDefinedFunctions].[FromCamelCase]
GO
```

**On execute, I am getting this error.**

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FromCamelCase, Line 2
Cannot find the type 'nvarchar(MAX)', because it does not exist or you do not 
have permission.
```

I have tried changing the type from `nvarchar` to just `varchar`. I have also tried changing the size from `MAX` to 4000 and also just 50.

*Here is my C# method, for reference.*

```cs
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static string FromCamelCase(string val)
{
    if (val == null) return string.Empty;
    
    val = val.Replace("_", "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(val.Length + 10);
    bool first = true;
    char lastChar = '\0';
    
    foreach (char ch in val)
    {
        if (!first && (char.IsUpper(ch) || char.IsDigit(ch) && !char.IsDigit(lastChar)))
            sb.Append(' ');
    
        sb.Append(ch);
        first = false;
        lastChar = ch;
    }
    
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Making that change worked when performed for both references. Pls add it an an answer in case future visitors come across this. My other function uses `[datetime2]` quite happily. thank you for helping

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the brackets from around the data type name: `RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)`. The double brackets mean it's interpreted as a user-defined data type called "NVARCHAR(MAX)" (one word) and [quoted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) because of the parentheses in the name.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to keep brackets for whatever reason, [you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26578542/241211). Move the closing bracket to exclude the `(MAX)` like so:

```sql
RETURNS [NVARCHAR](MAX)
```