# Column, parameter, or variable #10: Cannot find data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes, create-table

I'm trying to create table from template code.

This template code is working:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    (
    [Field1] [int] NULL,
    [Field2] [float] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But if I put varchar(10):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    (
    [Field1] [int] NULL,
    [Field2] [varchar(10)] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I get error:

```
Msg 2715, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
Column, parameter, or variable #2: Cannot find data type varchar(10).
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem are brackets []. You have to put only `varchar` into brackets: `[varchar](10)`

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    (
    [Field1] [int] NULL,
    [Field2] [varchar](10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Or you can also remove the brackets:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
    (
    [Field1] int NULL,
    [Field2] varchar(10) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```